# C# How not to lock USB drive safely removal while reading data from it?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

So my application is reading a lot of files from the USB drives users put into their PCs. Right know it works well, however the user can't safely remove the USB drive while my application is reading from it. If the user wants to remove the USB drive it is not a big deal for the application.

How can I structure my code so that it would be possible for user to safely remove the drive while my application is reading files from it? Right now I'm using Directory.GetFiles for file enumeration and File.ReadAllBytes for reading files in a loop. Is there any File I/O operations that won't block the USB drive from removing it? Is there a way to bind the event of USB drive removal and stop reading files if it occurs?

Comment: Try/catch can catch exceptions from System.IO....is that what you're looking for?

Comment: "safe removal" isnt needed anyway for most usb drives... usually only for USB harddisks that have the write cache enabled.